# How to write 2d array of string in file?

Tags: python

I have array like this.

```
nplist=['brinjal','cabbage','chickpea',..]
area=[664.5, 556.7,778.9,..]
```

I am doing like this

```
f = open('file.txt', 'wb')
for i in range(len(area)):
    f.write("%s %s\n" % (nplist[i], area[i]))
f.close()
```

But it does not gives the proper output.
It should be:

```
brinjal 664.5
cabbage 556.7
chickpe 778.9
```

Comment: How the 'proper output' actually is?

Comment: That does not look like an `array`.

Comment: Just remove the `\n` in you `write` statement.  The `\n` means newline.

Comment: I just noticed, what do `nplist` and `area` are? How are they related to `array`?

Comment: @Juan T-Sorry for mistake.Now I corrected it.Please See Correction.

Comment: @PruthviPatel Considering you're using 'wb', it shouldn't be readable... You are writing to the file in binary, so you shouldn't expect readable lines. Instead, just use 'w'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the flag `'wb'` you are opening the file in binary, so it is expecting a bytes-like object. Just change that line to:

```
f = open('file.txt', 'w')
```